# WPF. Двусторонний байндинг на Calendar SelectedDates

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте!!!
Все просто. Есть контрол в WPF-Calendar. Необходимо выбирать несколько дат из календаря. и наоборот отмечать добавленные в список даты в календаре.

Т.е. двусторонний байндинг на SelectedDates. Но как и во многих контролах для коллекций  (ListView, ListBox) нету нормального байндинга на множественное выделение. Используя событие выделения элемент можно формировать список выделенных дат, но вот как обратно выделять даты в Calendar?

```
            <Calendar  Name="TournamentCalendar"  Grid.Column="5" FirstDayOfWeek="Monday" SelectionMode="MultipleRange" SelectedDates="{Binding Path=SelectedDateTimes}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedDatesChanged">
                    <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="AssignDates">
                        <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding SelectedDates, ElementName=TournamentCalendar}"/>
                    </cal:ActionMessage>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Calendar>
```

во ViewModel

```
    public void AssignDates(SelectedDatesCollection dates)
    {
               //Добавляем дату
    }
```

Может как то еще обойтись?
Пытался искать сторонние контролы но все платные(((, в частности WPFExtensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш случай один из примеров того, что иногда возникает необходимость вызова метода из кодбихайнд, т.е. установление связи View <- ViewModel.

Прямо над `public partial class MainWindow` напишем интерфейс

```
public interface ICodeBehind
{
    void SelectManyDates(List<DateTime> manyDates);
}
```

Унаследуем `MainWindow` от этого интерфейса, и реализуем его

```
public void SelectManyDates(List<DateTime> manyDates)
{
     SelectedDatesCollection theDates = Calendar1.SelectedDates;

     //в цикле foreach пробегаем по manyDates и добавляем в theDates
 }
```

Перейдем во ViewModel и создадим свойство для связи с кодбихайнд

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Ссылка на MainWindow.xaml.cs
    /// </summary>
    public ICodeBehind MainWindowCodeBehind { get; set; }
```

Вернемся в кодбихайнд и привяжемся к этому свойству либо в конструкторе `MainWindow`, либо в событии `Load`

```
//ссылыка на MainViewModel
((MainViewModel)DataContext).MainWindowCodeBehind = this;
```

Теперь во ViewModel вы можете вызвать так

```
MainWindowCodeBehind.SelectManyDates(dates);
```

Comment: Попробую!! в общем понял. Странно что такие простые вещи не реализованы из коробки.

Comment: у меня      ((AppViewModel)DataContext).AppWindowCodeBehind = this; dataContext == NULL. Посмотрите мой ответ выше.

Answer (score 1):

ВСЕ РАБОТАЕТ. нужно в методе OnActivated привязываться.

```
    protected override void OnActivated(EventArgs e)
    {
        ((AppViewModel)DataContext).AppWindowCodeBehind = this;
        base.OnActivated(e);
    }
```

Comment: Очень рад, что получилось :)

Answer (score 0):

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for AppView.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class AppView : Window, ICodeBehind
{
    public AppView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ((AppViewModel)DataContext).AppWindowCodeBehind = this;
    }


    public void SelectManyDates(BindableCollection<DateTime> manyDates)
    {
        SelectedDatesCollection theDates = Calendar.SelectedDates;
        //в цикле foreach пробегаем по manyDates и добавляем в theDates
        foreach (var date in manyDates)
        {
            theDates.Add(date);
        }
    }
}
```

`DataContext` равен `NULL` в конструкторе. Я использую `Caliburn.Micro`. Что не так?

Comment: Я описывал случай, когда ViewModel подключена к View вот так:  `<Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>` я не пользуюсь фреймворками. Ищите как ваш Фреймворк подключает к View нужную ViewModel. Может через ViewModelLocator. Поищите в XAML может подкючение идет к DataContext какой-то Grid или Panel, тогда придется переписать строку в конструкторе. А так все работает, проверено на нескольких проектах.